# Replace Do loop with Nest

Tags: functional-style, permutation

```
a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Do[a2 = DeleteCases[a1, x1];
  Do[a3 = DeleteCases[a2, x2];
   Do[a4 = DeleteCases[a3, x3];
    Do[Sow@{x1, x2, x3, x4};
     , {x4, a4}]
    , {x3, a3}]
   , {x2, a2}]
  , {x1, a1}] // Reap // Last
```

I would like replace my code with `Nest`, I have tried this

```
a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Nest[Table[{i, j}, {i, a1}, {j, DeleteCases[#, i]}]~Flatten~1 &, a1, 3]
```

but it worked incorrect.

Comment: Why don't you use simply `Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4}]` ???

Comment: Like this :                                              `Select[Tuples[a1, 4], Length@Union@# == 4 &]`

Comment: @Tangshutao Your method consume too much memory, also `Select[Tuples[Range@4, 4], Unequal @@ # &]`

Comment: @chyaong,+1,Thank you!Your method also takes less time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write something like this

```
a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Nest[Flatten[Outer[Append, {#}, Complement[a1, #], 1] & /@ #, 2] &, Transpose@{a1}, 3]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 3, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4, 2}, {1, 4, 2, 3}, 
>  {1, 4, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 1}, 
>  {2, 4, 1, 3}, {2, 4, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2, 4}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 2, 1, 4}, 
>  {3, 2, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 2, 1}, {4, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 1, 3, 2}, 
>  {4, 2, 1, 3}, {4, 2, 3, 1}, {4, 3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}
> ```

However, as Artes pointed out it is the same as `Permutations`

```
 % == Permutations[a1]
```

> True

Answer (score 1):

```
a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Nest[Table[{a}~Join~b, {a, a1}, {b, Select[#, FreeQ[#, a] &]}]~Flatten~1 &, {{}}, Length@a1]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 3, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4, 2}, {1, 4, 2, 
>     3}, {1, 4, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 4}, {2, 3, 
>     4, 1}, {2, 4, 1, 3}, {2, 4, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2, 4}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 
>     2, 1, 4}, {3, 2, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 2, 1}, {4, 1, 2, 
>     3}, {4, 1, 3, 2}, {4, 2, 1, 3}, {4, 2, 3, 1}, {4, 3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 
>     2, 1}}